# Uipath connection to MySQL

Tags: uipath

Has anyone ever connected to a MySQL remote server using uipath? Is this possible. I've tried using the standard activities but am unable. I understand that I may need to install the odbc driver, then create a connection. Is it possible to then send sql from uipath to the linked server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the information. I followed the steps and able to solve the problem.

- Install mysql
- Install Mysql odbc driver
- create USER DSN
- While creating connection use the ODBC DATA SOURCE option
- In next window select the DSN created in third step under system or user Data source name

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use connect to MYSQL database using UIPath, by installing Mysql-ODBC connector of 32-bit(x86) and creating a system/user DSN.

I have tried and it is working fine.

Please revert for any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the remote server and pass the SQL queries to fetch the data.

Which version of UiPath you using now (Community or Enterprise)?